# jquery drag and drop and save state in Database

Tags: c#, jquery, sql

Hello i work in inettuts jquery plugin for Sortable box and i save the position in cookies 
but now i want to save in database(sql server) , C# code ??

Ok

Please go to this Link : [link text](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html)

i want to save state this Box in Database by C# code

Answer (score 1):

If you do a postback to the server (ie. click a button) you can get the values from the cookies like this:
`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CookieName"].Value`

Then you use the code from this pdf (Working with databases) to open a connection to the database and save the cookie value there: http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/content/cheats/CS_Language_Basics.pdf

---

If you want to do it by using AJAX then you need some event on the client-side that is handled by jQuery and do a AJAX post to a ASHX page (Generic Handler) where you can get the post data like this: `context.Request["PostDataVariableName"]`

Hope it helps! ;)